# javascript strange behavior, works with alert and when I move the cursor out of window

Tags: javascript, html

I have several small images and one big one.
When my cursor is on a small one, I want it to take the place of the big one using `onmouseover`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/div/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<img id="0" src="images/voiture.jpg"  width="300px"/></br>
<img id="1" src="images/voiture.jpg" width="100px" onmouseover="f(1)" />
<img  id="2" src="images/voiture1.jpg" width="100px" onmouseover="f(2)" />
<img  id="3" src="images/voiture2.jpg" width="100px" onmouseover="f(3)"/>
<img  id="4" src="images/voiture3.jpg" width="100px" onmouseover="f(4)" />
<script>
function f(num)
{
document.getElementById("0").setAttribute('src',document.getElementById(num).src);
}
</script>
</noscript>
</html>
```

It doesn't work and produces a strange behavior:
When there is an alert it works well, otherwise when I am at picture 3 it doesn't (nothing happens).
However, when I move over picture 2, picture 3 appears well (but I want the picture in which my cursor is... :( )

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably not the cause but an _id_ (for maximum compatibility and usability) should begin with a _letter_ `a-zA-Z`

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6nh73pbc/

Comment: CSS IDs may not begin with a number, so it's possible that you're running into a problem there. In addition, you've got a "parfait.js" script. What's going on there? In addition, you've got a stray `</noscript>` tag in there for some reason. Finally, you need to work on your function naming. `f` as a function name tells nobody anything about how you want this to work, and will make it a lot harder for someone (possibly yourself) to come back to this code in the future.